# Android - Get Current location of user on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, emulation

Is it possible to show our current posotion on Android emulator?
If yes how?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the latitude and longitude in case of emulator because emulator do not have gps detection hardrware to get current location.

```
telnet localhost 5554
geo fix <longitude value> <latitude value> For ex: geo fix 68.54546 37.5117579
```

Comment: @Rakesh Burbure have you installed telnet client and which computer os you are using.

Comment: sorry , i dont kno about this software.... if u have link of this software, then pls share with me...........Thank you

Comment: i have downloaded telnet client from http://www.windows7download.com/win7-dan-s-telnet/download-ygjcbwfs.html . but i dont know what to do afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

You can fake GPS location data on emulator using DDMS  which is explained here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#ops-location and here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData.

Answer (score 1):

You can interact with an emulator instance through its shell.

1. Start emulator.
2. From terminal run `telnet localhost 5554`, you are now in emulator shell.
3. Type `help`,it will show available commands , like faking a call, sms, battery etc.
4. To know more about a command type `help <command name>`.
5. Type `help geo`, it will print available location commands.
6. Try  `geo fix 1 1` .
7. Try more with other latitude and longitude values.