# Current position is not available to display map skobbler android sdk

Tags: android, skmaps

I have downloaded the skobbler demo app and run in emulator.When i click on position me button it shows that current position is not available.please help me to get out of this problem

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with your emulator's lack of GPS hardware.

You can work around that - see the following thread:
[Current location on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675789/current-location-on-emulator)

Comment: I have debugged in device.It shows "called unimplemented OpenGL ES API".please help me to proceed.